# In WebGPU am I supposed to load my function pointers in an initialise function beforehand?

Tags: webgpu

If I follow a WebGPU tutorial for Dawn(Google's implementation of WebGPU) the tutorial simply starts off immediately with:

WGPUInstanceDescriptor instance_info{ .nextInChain = nullptr };
wgpu_instance = wgpuCreateInstance(&instance_info);

When I do this my program crashes because it seems to call a function pointer which is currently null (or at least invalid). I have the feeling that you're supposed to manually load a proctable (the function pointers), but I can't find any information on how to do this. Is there an initialise function or something?

Comment: Does https://source.chromium.org/search?q=wgpuInstanceDescriptor%5C%20%5BA-Za-z_%5D%2B%5C%20%5C%3D&ss=chromium help?

Comment: What dawn library did you link against? There are a few ways to use dawn, one requires loading up a proc table but the other does.  I believe you want `webgpu_dawn` if you're using cmake.